# python beautifulsoup - how to go to next page while next page doesn't have an unique address

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to write a web crawler using beautifulsoup to extract the gene names from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=Celiac+disease

My code can get the result I want from the first page, but I don't know how to write a code to have my program move to the next page. After I click the "next" button, I get a new address which has nothing related to the previous page. 
For example, the first page has an address https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=Celiac+disease, but the next page's address is https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene (still shows related results to Celiac disease, though)

I have looked up google and stackoverflow to see if there are any article related to this problem. But I could only find articles about pages coming with similar addresses and (for me) logically to follow the their tracks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

gene_result = []

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=Celiac+disease"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

tbody = soup.find("tbody")
a_href = tbody.find_all("a")

for x in a_href:
    gene = x.contents[0]
    gene_result.append(gene)

print(gene_result)
```

The code goes fine crawling first page and I got good result:

```
['CTLA4', 'HLA-DQA1', 'IL2', 'IL21', 'CCR3', 'CELIAC2', 'ATXN2', 'SH2B3', 'HLA-DQB1', 'CELIAC5', 'TAGAP', 'CELIAC7', 'CELIAC13', 'CELIAC12', 'CELIAC11', 'CELIAC10', 'CELIAC9', 'CELIAC8', 'CELIAC6', 'KIAA1109']
```

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked into using something like selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such websites, you need to use something called a [selenium webdriver with python.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

You will need to simulate clicking of the "next" button through this webdriver from your python code and then read the html_source into BeautifulSoup.